Required RVR for Landing
There are a few questions out there on this topic, but I have some confusion about the wording and the meaning of RVR and its usage,
"The touch-down zone RVR is always controlling. If reported and relevant, the mid point and stop end RVR are also controlling. The minimum RVR value for the mid-point is 125 m or the RVR required for the touch-down zone if less, and 75 m for the stop-end. For aeroplanes equipped with a roll-out guidance or control system, the minimum RVR value for the mid-point is 75 m.
Note: “Relevant”, in this context, means that part of the runway used during the high speed phase of the landing down to a speed of approximately 60 knots."

"...Or the RVR required for touch-down zone if less..." Does this that if the RVR is less than 125m, use the touch down zone RVR?

The word "Relevant", does this mean that if the plane will be over 60kts at the mid point, then the RVR minima here is to be considered? but if plans to be less than 60kts at the end point, no need to consider the minima there?

What is the touchdown zone RVR? would this be what is on the approach charts?


Thank you!

Welcome to Av.SE. It would be helpful if you can provide a link to the document that you are quoting, because context matters when working to explain a particular statement. Thanks!

Thank you! The document is actually from the company's OM-A, but I think it must have been an extract from an ICAO annex. But maybe just to confirm my final understanding from a high level perspective, its essentially trying to make sure you apply the right RVR, based on your approach type and landing distance required?


If you are performing a CAT3 without DH where RVR required for touchdown zone is less than 125m, the requirement for the middle zone is the same as it is for the touchdown zone. Note: you have to perform an automatic rollout.

Yes, but consider them as zones. So if you have calculated the required landing distance of about 2km, the last kilometer of a three kilometer runway is not relevant.

Assuming you have the required equipment, training and all the ground facilities including the lights are operational, then yes.


As a sidenote to question three, for every approach you are flying from visual approaches to low visibility operations the required RVR for approach is always required only to be available in the touchdown zone. For middle and stop ends, 125m and 75m applies.
